# Web (javascript - requestFullscreen) fullscreen element resizes (height is smaller) after first human touch to screen on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, fullscreen

I basically found that when I open fullscreen mode (.requestFullscreen()) on canvas (with threejs scene) on my Android device (Android 13, One UI 5.1), then when I touch anywhere on screen, then fullscreen element is resized and its height is now smaller by approx 50 px (possible connection to bottom bar with software android back/home buttons; but this bar is hidden and opens on slide). This results in very ugly shift/jump of anything that is relatively positioned and I hate it.

I first found this strange behaviour with WebXR immersive AR session. Then I found that it also happens for simple requestFullscreen on canvas with threejs scene. I coundn't find anything that could change this stupid behaviour Or if I could manually trigger this change to prevent this jump on first user click.

I tried manipulation with DOM but it didnt triggered this resize. It only happened after human touch.